# installing nylas N1.deb

Tags: 14.04, python

```
   raymond@akornor:~/Downloads$ sudo gdebi N1.deb
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree        
   Reading state information... Done
   Building data structures... Done 
   Building data structures... Done 
   This package is uninstallable
   Cannot install 'python:amd64'
   raymond@akornor:~/Downloads$ uname -a
   Linux akornor 3.19.0-39-generic #44~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 2 10:01:00             UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

i get this error when i try to install Nylas N1.deb on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Where did you get `N1.deb` from?

Comment: downloaded it from their website -- ofcourse

Comment: Is your system 64-bit or 32-bit? please [edit] your question to include the output of command `uname -a`

Comment: 32-bit -- ive done that

Comment: It appears that the software maintainers do not currently provide a 32-bit deb package: see this outstanding feature request [32-bit deb builds](https://github.com/nylas/N1/issues/139)

Comment: OK, which website - getting there...

Comment: https://edgehill.nylas.com/download?platform=linux&_ga=1.36848873.898709698.1448912177

Answer (score 2):

Best way to install and update Nylas N1, until it's not in repo is to use :

```
$ wget -O N1.deb "https://edgehill.nylas.com/download?platform=linux" && \
sudo gdebi --n N1.deb && \
rm N1.deb
```